# UnassignedReferenceException in camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLock : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float mouseSensetivity = 100f;

    public Transform playerBody;

    float xRotation = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensetivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensetivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

    }
}
```

I really don't see any problem and you can see the code it's only on one object and it's the camera i got it from a tutorial.

[the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8wyR.png)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you drag your playerBody transform from the hierarchy into the playerBody variable slot in your MouseLock component?